# What is meant by "Shouldn't be relied upon" in GetAsyncKeyState() defn

Tags: c++, winapi

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState. However, you should not rely on this last behavior; [..]
>
> Although the least significant bit of the return value indicates whether the key has been pressed since the last query, due to the pre-emptive multitasking nature of Windows, another application can call GetAsyncKeyState and receive the "recently pressed" bit instead of your application. The behavior of the least significant bit of the return value is retained strictly for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications (which are non-preemptive) and should not be relied upon.

In my program, I'm only interested in the return value for where the key is currently down. Namely, as defined by msdn, when both the least and most significant bits are set (-32767) (and this is the way it is working right now.). However, must I also check for 32767 (the value without the least sig. bit) In the case that, like it says, the least significant bit gets intercepted by another program, or is "unreliable", whatever that means.

Comment: Note "most significant bit".  So simply use `bool leftShiftDown = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) < 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, yeah, basically. Easier to just check only the most significant bit and ignore the least significant entirely, though.

> must I also check for 32767 (the value without the least sig. bit)

That's not right - the value will be -32768 (assuming two's complement):

```
1000 0000 0000 0001   -32767
1000 0000 0000 0000   -32768
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10795798/560648); it's strange to me that this value is packed into a `short`, but there we go.

Comment: I was wondering why it was a short as well.. For some reason my code isn't working as it was before now. So something's up.

Comment: So the correct method appears to be -32767||-32768, thanks for the correction! Otherwise, (with just -32768, for example) it seems to behave like the normal windows key input, where when holding p it does (p....p.p.p.p.p) instead of (ppppppppppppppp) the latter being the one i want.

Comment: @Chimps: Just check that the value, when `AND`ed with `-32768`, is convertible to `true` :)

Comment: It's now a `short` because the bit pattern was defined at a time when `int` and `short` had the same size (16-bit Windows).

Comment: @BoPersson: But, I think, clearly a single byte is even four times larger than required for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`GetAsyncKeyState()` tries to determine if it was pressed since you last called it, which makes it unreliable. Something else may have called out and effectively reset that flag so you'll never receive it.

Comment: You've got it exactly backwards.